# How should I deal with Search page for SEO

Tags: seo, search

A website I'm building has a product search page with many options. Name, size, category, etc.

Currently the url is search.php and the GET string (when the user submits the form) effectively just returns `search.php?name=abc&size=3,6,8&category=12&available=yes` etc.

Is this best for SEO or should I construct some URL like `search/name/abc/size/3,6,8/category/12/available/yes` or similar? I could just exclude the entire `search.php` page in the robots file, which seems sensible, as it's not a massively optimised page for any particular keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, Google have recommended using `robots.txt` to [block search results pages](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/).

Whilst their [Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769) no longer say this explicitly, it's still considered good practice to block indexing these pages. I like the technique [Yoast uses](https://yoast.com/blocking-your-sites-search-results/), which involves including a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>` tag. This way Google can still crawl the page and find links to your products, but won't index the page itself.